# How to initialRouteName in to createTabBottomNavigator at screen Menu

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How to InitialRouteName to createTabNavigator, at MenuScreen position InitialRouteName.

This is for a new React-Native, running to Windows 10

```
const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Order: {
        screen: OrderScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon type = 'AntDesign' name = 'search1' style = {{fontSize: 22, color:`${tintColor}`}} />
            ),
            title: 'Order'
        }
    },
    Payment: {
        screen: PaymentScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon type = 'AntDesign' name = 'search1' style = {{fontSize: 22, color:`${tintColor}`}} />
            ),
            title: 'Payment'
        }
    },
    Menu: {
        screen: MenuScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon type = 'AntDesign' name = 'search1' style = {{fontSize: 22, color:`${tintColor}`}} />
            ),
            title: 'Menu'
        }
    },
    Chat: {
        screen: ChatScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon type = 'AntDesign' name = 'search1' style = {{fontSize: 22, color:`${tintColor}`}} />
            ),
            title: 'Chat'
        }
    },
    Setting: {
        screen: SettingScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon type = 'AntDesign' name = 'search1' style = {{fontSize: 22, color:`${tintColor}`}} />
            ),
            title: 'Setting'
        }
    },
},{
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#fbda91',
        inactiveTintColor: 'white',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#fb8691',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: '#fb8691',
        borderTopWidth: 0,
    }
})
```

I except the output of InitialRouteName Order change to Menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [createBottomTabNavigator documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#bottomtabnavigatorconfig), you can use the second parameter of the method for set some configurations, it has `initialRouteName` and you can set it to `Menu` as you want, like below:

```
const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {/* your routes*/},
  {initialRouteName: "Menu"}, // <-- you should pass this config object to the method 
);
```

Comment: happy navigating :)